# MySQL Table Engines

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engines

MyISAM

- Default engine
- No Transaction support
- Good for Heavy data reading
- Bad for write calls: table level locking

InnoDB

- Transaction safe
- Good for Heavy write calls: row level locking
- Supports foreign keys referential integrity constraints

Is InnoDB bad for data reading??? What other storage engines should i be familar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, InnoDB is not "bad" for data reading; in fact, I tend to use it as a default engine for all of my tables. Transactions and true relational features outweigh any minor read-performance benefit that you might get from MyISAM (in my opinion).

**Edited to add:** MyISAM *is* faster than InnoDB because it is simpler. But, unless you're doing some really high-volume stuff or are using an ancient machine as your database server, you're not likely to see a difference in daily operation.

Other storage engines to be familiar with are `Memory` for really fast, non-persistent data storage and `CSV` which I will use on occasion as part of data export processes.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) has a comprehensive overview of MySQL Storage Engines.